# Robot framework [ ERROR ] Unexpected error: IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Tags: python, robotframework

I have this weird error that I have never seen before. I ran an RF automation regression test using Chrome and after a while, I got this error which basically stops the test execution and does not provide any test results.

I also noticed this new text line that I haven't seen before during text execution:

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:12306/devtools/browser/df1c8bcc-867c-41bc-a9b4-c364bdfafec2
>
> (The test scripts have been used before & passed without any issues)
>
> W8-BENE date format - ddMMMMMyyyyDot :: This is to test the differ...
>   DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:12537/devtools/browser/6d32afb6-90f2-46d4-a18a-001fa61d2444
>
> [ ERROR ] Unexpected error: IOError: [Errno 0] Error Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\utils\application.py", line 83,
>   in _execute
>       rc = self.main(arguments, **options)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\run.py", line 445, in main
>       result = suite.run(settings)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\model.py", line
>   248, in run
>       self.visit(runner)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\model\testsuite.py", line
>   161, in visit
>       visitor.visit_suite(self)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\model\visitor.py", line
>   87, in visit_suite
>       suite.tests.visit(self)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\model\itemlist.py", line
>   76, in visit
>       item.visit(visitor)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\model\testcase.py", line
>   74, in visit
>       visitor.visit_test(self)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\runner.py", line
>   151, in visit_test
>       result)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\runner.py", line
>   182, in _run_teardown
>       exception = self._run_setup_or_teardown(teardown)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\runner.py", line
>   201, in _run_setup_or_teardown
>       StepRunner(self._context).run_step(data, name=name)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\steprunner.py",
>   line 57, in run_step
>       return runner.run(step, context)
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\librarykeywordrunner.py",
>   line 56, in run
>       return return_value   File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\statusreporter.py", line
>   54, in **exit**
>       context.end_keyword(result)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\running\context.py", line
>   179, in end_keyword
>       self.output.end_keyword(keyword)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\output.py", line
>   65, in end_keyword
>       LOGGER.end_keyword(kw)
>
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\logger.py", line
>   195, in end_keyword
>       logger.end_keyword(keyword)
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\console\verbose.py", line
>   62, in end_keyword
>       self._writer.keyword_marker(kw.status)
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\console\verbose.py", line
>   136, in keyword_marker
>       self._clear_status()
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\console\verbose.py", line
>   124, in _clear_status
>       self._write_info()
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\console\verbose.py", line
>   90, in _write_info
>       self._stdout.write(self._last_info)
>
> File
>   "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\robot\output\console\highlighting.py",
>   line 51, in write
>       self.stream.write(console_encode(text, stream=self.stream))
>
> W8-BENE date format - ddMMMMMyyyyDot :: This is to test the differ...
>   C:\Development\robot-scripts\WebApp>

Has anyone had the same issue? I can't seem to find any solution. I uninstalled and reinstalled everything even update all the web drivers.

Comment: Can you let us know your chrome version,RF version,selenium version ,and paste ur code of Robot scripts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after update to WIN 10. Just did fresh python install and it works fine for me. also look here: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2709